# difference between fstab and mount -a?

Tags: linux, debian, mount

I have an smb share on a NAS that I am trying to mount on a Debian box (RaspPi). So far so good.

I added the following entry in my fstab file:

```
//192.168.1.xx/yann /home/pi/buffalo     cifs    guest,uid=1000 0 0
```

but at boot time, the volume is not mounted. Right after though, if I do :

```
$ sudo mount -a
```

then the volume is mounted and all is well.

I always though that `mount -a` was just replaying the fstab file so if it works with `mount -a` then it should work at boot time. Obviously it's not quite right.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably already answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/399643/cifs-mount-through-fstab-not-mounting-at-boot)

Comment: @Alex : Not really, no. It talks about a mistake between '/' and '\' which I definitely did not make. Also they do not explain the difference with 'mount-a'...

Comment: The answers in @Alex's link cover adding `_netdev`, as suggested in Craig Watson's answer below. (Thanks Alex, I didn't know about that option.)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `_netdev` to your fstab options section on that line:

```
//192.168.1.xx/yann /home/pi/buffalo cifs _netdev,guest,uid=1000 0 0
```

The reason why `mount -a` works and boot-time mounting doesn't is likely that the kernel is trying to mount the filesystem before your network interface has the chance to come up.

This will ensure that the filesystem is only mounted after your network interface initialises.

Comment: Still not working, although I like the theory here. Do you know what sort of log file can tell me what happens at boot time regarding mount ?